Maven dependency based on environment variable
I have java application with Maven. For one profile I need to use driver from environment variable location instead of dependency from jar.
It is possible to add one of dependencies to classpath based on environment variable? I cannot set absolute path because there are a lot of environments and I have no control where $ORACLE_HOME is.
For now i use java -cp to run the app, but I would like to use 'java -jar' as earlier (there are a lot of people in my company used to this so I would like to avoid mess)
I tried adding path to manifest but it seems not working.Also I tried set dependency as provided and with scope 'system' but maven says 'systemPath' need absolute path to jar.
I would like to start my app with java -jar and with driver from $ORACLE_HOME location but I'm not sure it is even possible.

For what do you need the driver? How many different drivers exist?
